# cssmin grunt plugin generates incorrect source urls in sourcemap

Tags: css, gruntjs, source-maps, grunt-contrib-cssmin, gruntfile

cssmin grunt plugin `grunt-contrib-cssmin` trims leading slash in css sourcemap sources url, thus making css mapping incorrect. Meanwhile after editing sourcemap file by hand (adding leading slash to each source url) everything seems to be mapped correctly. Original sourcemap file is taken from annotation in original css (unminified), which is generated correctly by other grunt plugins.

My file structure:

```
web (resource root)
├─css
│ └─..(css files)
└─less
  └─..(less files)
```

Sourcemap of original (unminified) css – sources urls are correct. Generated by *grunt-contrib-less* and *grunt-autoprefixer* respectively:

```
{"version":3,"sources":["/less/base/normalize.less","/less/base/boilerplate.less"...
```

Sourcemap of minified css – leading slashes for source files disappeared. Generated by *grunt-contrib-cssmin*:

```
{"version":3,"sources":["less/base/normalize.less","less/base/boilerplate.less"...
```

Part of my *gruntfile.js*:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    cssmin: {
      options: {
        shorthandCompacting: false,
        sourceMap: true,
        roundingPrecision: -1
      },
      target: {
        files: {
          'web/css/style.min.css': 'web/css/style.css'
        }
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Here's my solution. Hope this helps anyone at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612422/grunt-cssmin-cleancss-source-map-rebasing/34654040#34654040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now I solved this problem with `grunt-string-replace` plugin. I configured my `gruntfile.js` so that it adds leading slashes to source files in sourcemap:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    'string-replace': {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'web/css/style.min.css.map': 'web/css/style.min.css.map'
        },
        options: {
          replacements: [{
            pattern: /"([^"])*(less\/)/g,
            replacement: '"/less/'
          }]
        }
      }
    }

    // other code

  });
};
```

Well, it's a hack, because it requires additional grunt plugin. But it solved the problem.